# Can clang build executables with "dsym" debug information?

Tags: macos, clang

According to [technical note 2123](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html), in xcode you can build executables with "dsym" debug information, which puts the debug info in a separate file (instead of embedding it in the executable). We're building our apps from the command line, instead of using xcode directly - is there a way to tell clang to do this on the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Xcode is using `dsymutil` to create the dsym file from the original executable:

```
/Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil executable -o executable.dSYM
```

Actually, it's not a file but a bundle (directory), displayed by the Finder as a "file package".

See `man dsymutil`.

Comment: Should I strip the executable afterwards?

Comment: This works well to generate the dSYM data. Thanks. But Instruments will not show source code even though it finds the dSYM file. If I use Xcode to build, I do see source code in Instruments profile runs.